# How to convert matlab vector to 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a vector `s`, which is of size `1*163840` which  comes from  `sizeX * sizeY * sizeZ = 64 * 40 * 60`. I want to convert the 1*163840 vector to a 3-dimensional matrix, which has  64 in x-axis, 40 in y-axis, and 64 in z-axis.

*What is the easiest way to convert it?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use reshape to do it easily:

```
new_matrix = reshape(s, 64, 40, 60);
```

Comment: BTW, if one wants `sizeX` to be 64, shouldn't 64 be the size of the second dimension?

Answer (score 1):

`reshape` is the right way of re-aranging elements into a different shape, as pointed out by [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24602278/1714410).
However, one must pay attention to the order of the elements in the vector and in the resulting array:

```
 >> v = 1:12;
 >> reshape( v, 3, 4 )
 1     4     7    10
 2     5     8    11
 3     6     9    12
```

Matlab arranges the elements "column first".
If you want to get a "row first" arrangement, you'll need to be a bit more sophisticated and use `permute` as well

```
>> permute( reshape( v, 4, 3 ), [2 1] ) 
 1     2     3     4
 5     6     7     8
 9    10    11    12
```

See how we `reshape` to 4-by-3 (and **not** 3-by-4) and then transpose the result using `permute` command.

Answer (score 0):

initialize the matrix like so:

```
smatrix=zeros(64,40,60) // here you get an empty 3D matrix of the size you wanted.
```

use for loops to populate the matrix using your vector

```
for indexx=1:64
   for indexy=1:40
       for indexz=1:60
           smatrix(indexx,indexy,indexz)=s(40*60*(indexx-1)+60*(indexy-1)+indexz);
       end
   end
end
```

Comment: @rayryeng it is also much faster. Matlab will do some graceful memory re-arrangement instead of visiting every element in a huge array.

Comment: nice effort, but I have to downvote: nested loop instead of `reshape`?? It is bad understanding and practice. It's like digging a well for a glace of water - you simply don't do this anymore...